# Bevelling the edge around a hole results in starburst

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

I'm a beginner trying to learn hard surface modelling. I've extruded a hole in my hard surface mesh and bevelled the inside edges to create a round hole. Now I'm trying to bevel the edge around the hole, but bevel only gets me a big starburst shape instead of a bevel. What could be causing this?
[image]

This is what my vertices look like:
[image]

Blend file:
https://pasteall.org/media/2/c/2cc62bc9caef8b594a1c43d1f0770f90.blend

Comment: Hello, I can't help but notice that pretty much all of your problems come from suboptimal topology. You should try to model with quads for this kind of shapes. Maybe this will help https://topologyguides.com/

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: At the very least, that square around the circle needs to be bigger than the amount you're trying to bevel, there is no room for the new geometry to be created.

Comment: Thanks for this comment and link, @Gorgious! I've suspected as much, but I'm sort of stumped about how to make this in a better way. My first try at modelling this item I tried using booleans to make these holes, but that really messes up the mesh. This time around I've tried using loop cuts and extrudes, but for some reason I have more trouble. I'll read through your link! :)

Comment: @JachymMichal yes, that's also helpful! I'm remodelling the entire object for the third time now, starting out with square subdivides and trying to keep to quads. Hopefully It'll work better this time around.